# how to call action from a view of another action?

Tags: php, yii, scope

how I can call an action from the view of another action, knowing that the 2 actions are belong to the same controller ?

the controller is named `FilesController`, and the requested action is named `Subscribing`.

Comment: Are you redirecting to this action, or just calling it to get data?

Answer (score 0):

Actions shouldn't really be called from within the view. The view should only have data fed into it that will be represented by the view code itself. Views can, however, call other views. You may want to look at how your logic is structured to see if there's a different way to go about doing this.

There is one way, though, and that's via ajax. You can make an ajax call via Javascript/jQuery to a controller, and then have that controller send back a view, which is then placed into a specific area of the original view file.

Comment: so how I can call the action by ajax ?

Comment: That's a separate question, but if you are using jQuery, look in the documentation on how to make an ajax call. The url of the ajax call should be the path to the action you wish to call. If you are returning a view, make sure your ajax call is looking for a plain text response (not json).

Comment: I'am newbie in JQuery :(